# Sampling combinations of two variables without repeated combinations over several runs

Tags: r, sampling

EDIT: If I am not mistaken, the problem outlined below can also be expressed simpler in the following way:

Distribute a variable `run` (ranging from 1 to 5 with each value appearing exactly 5 times) randomly over all possible combinations of the two variables `var1` (1 to 5) and `var2` (a to e) in a way that the following condition is met: Each value of `var2` may only appear once for each value of `run`.

---

I hope that CrossValidated is the correct place for this. If not, please point me to the right place. My problem is associated with the sampling process itself, so I chose CrossValidated.

Alright, I have the following problem which seemed pretty easy to me ... until I've tried solving it. This might be a nice brain twister for some of you.

- I have 2 variables (`var1` and `var2`). Both can have 5 possible values (1-5 and a-e).
- I want to create 5 "compositions" of combinations of `var1` and `var2`. Hence, my goal is to have a result dataset with 25 rows. This result dataset has to satisfy the following two conditions:

1. Each combination of `var1` and `var2` (e.g., 4-a) should only appear once in the final dataset.
2. In each "composition", each value of `var2` should only appear once.

I wrote R code to do that. I will explain the code and the problem I am running into below the code.

```
urn <- expand.grid(composition = 1:5, var1 = 1:5, var2 = letters[1:5])

result <- data.frame()
for (comp.i in 1:5) {
  if (comp.i %% 1 == 0) cat("Composition", comp.i, "\n")
  comp.urn <- urn[urn$composition == comp.i,]
  comp.result <- data.frame(composition = numeric(), var1 = numeric(), var2 = character())
  for (var1.i in 1:5) {
    var1.urn <- comp.urn[comp.urn$var1 == var1.i,]
    drawn <- var1.urn[sample(1:nrow(var1.urn), 1),]
    while (drawn$var2 %in% comp.result$var2 | paste0(drawn$var1, "-", drawn$var2) %in% result$combination) {
      drawn <- var1.urn[sample(1:nrow(var1.urn), 1),]
    }
    comp.result <- rbind(comp.result, drawn)
  }
  comp.result$combination <- paste0(comp.result$var1, "-", comp.result$var2)
  result <- rbind(result, comp.result)
}
```

First, I create a global urn with all possible combinations. Then I iterate over "compositions" and get the part of the global urn which is currently relevant (this results in `comp.urn`). I then iterate over `var1` and draw one case from its combinations (from `var1.urn`). If `var2` of this case is already in the results for the current composition run (Condition 2 above) OR if the `var1`-`var2` combination is already in the global result (Condition 1 above), I draw again because one of the conditions is not met.

Now the problem: If, for example, 5-b is drawn in composition run 1, but in composition run 3, the only combination that is still left after 4 successful draws is 5-b, the `while` loop above never terminates because the two conditions cannot be satisfied at the same time.

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this problem. I've tried brute-forcing it by sampling 25 cases from the global urn and do this so often until both conditions are met by chance. However, in my real application, I have 43 composition runs, 43 possible values for var1 and var2. So brute-forcing won't work in a reasonable time frame.

I would greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want.

```
library(data.table)

setorder(
  as.data.table(
    expand.grid(
      var1 = 1:5,
      var2 = letters[1:5]
    )
  )[
    sample(25)
  ][
    , .(var1 = var1, run = 1:5), var2
  ][
    , 3:1
  ],
  run
)[]
#>     run var1 var2
#>  1:   1    4    b
#>  2:   1    5    a
#>  3:   1    5    c
#>  4:   1    3    e
#>  5:   1    1    d
#>  6:   2    1    b
#>  7:   2    3    a
#>  8:   2    1    c
#>  9:   2    1    e
#> 10:   2    3    d
#> 11:   3    5    b
#> 12:   3    2    a
#> 13:   3    2    c
#> 14:   3    2    e
#> 15:   3    2    d
#> 16:   4    3    b
#> 17:   4    1    a
#> 18:   4    3    c
#> 19:   4    4    e
#> 20:   4    5    d
#> 21:   5    2    b
#> 22:   5    4    a
#> 23:   5    4    c
#> 24:   5    5    e
#> 25:   5    4    d
```

The idea is to set the `run` by group using `var2` after shuffling.

Comment: It does indeed! Thanks a lot… pretty easy solution as soon as you‘re seeing it written down :)

Comment: I am now seeing that I've underspecified my question. Another condition would be that each value of `var1` should only appear once for each `run`.

Comment: Think of $n$ wrapping diagonals of length $n$ comprising a square matrix. Each diagonal is a run, and the rows/columns correspond to `var1` and `var2`. You can shuffle the runs and the ordering within the runs, but there's only one way to do it.

Comment: `dt <- data.frame(var1 = sequence(rep(5, 5)), var2 = sequence(rep(5, 5), 0:4) %% 5L + 1L, run = rep(sample(5), each = 5))[vapply(0:4, function(x) 5L*x + sample(5), integer(5)),]
`

Comment: You can also flip the rows/columns (doesn't matter which one), so that would be: `dt <- data.frame(var1 = abs(6L*sample(0:1, 1) - sequence(rep(5, 5))), var2 = sequence(rep(5, 5), 0:4) %% 5L + 1L, run = rep(sample(5), each = 5))[vapply(0:4, function(x) 5L*x + sample(5), integer(5)),]`

Comment: Wow, that is awesome. I think I understand what you did there and will now try to apply this to my "real-world" application.

Answer (score 1):

Same process as jblood94 just in tidy:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- as.data.frame(
  expand.grid(
    var1 = letters[1:5],
    var2 = 1:5)) %>%
  .[sample(nrow(.)),] %>%
  group_by(var2) %>%
  mutate(run = 1:5) %>%
  ungroup()
```